# Rolling condition with column criteria

Tags: r

I have combined two data sets, one which has values for every day over a period and the other has values on some days of the same period but not all.

My data looks like this:

```
   ID   Date        C1  C2  C3  C4  C5
1  AA   2019-11-25  6   6   6   0   0  
2  AA   2019-11-26  6   6   6   0   18 
3  AA   2019-11-27  5   6   6   0   0  
4  AA   2019-11-28  4   5   5   65  60 
5  AA   2019-11-29  5   6   6   0   0  
6  AA   2019-11-30  5   6   6   0   0  
7  AA   2019-12-01  5   6   6   0   0  
8  AA   2019-12-02  4   5   5   65  60 
9  BB   2019-11-25  6   6   6   20  0  
10 BB   2019-11-26  6   6   6   54  12 
11 BB   2019-11-27  5   6   6   0   0  
12 BB   2019-11-28  4   5   5   0   0  
13 BB   2019-11-29  5   6   6   90  33
```

Where C1:C3 are from the first data set and C4:C5 is from the second.

I am trying to create a new column to achieve the following:

```
   ID   Date        C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  New Column
1  AA   2019-11-25  6   6   6   0   0   1
2  AA   2019-11-26  6   6   6   0   18  0
3  AA   2019-11-27  5   6   6   0   0   1
4  AA   2019-11-28  4   5   5   65  60  0
5  AA   2019-11-27  5   6   6   0   0   1
6  AA   2019-11-27  5   6   6   0   0   2
7  AA   2019-11-27  5   6   6   0   0   3
8  AA   2019-11-28  4   5   5   65  60  0
9  BB   2019-11-25  6   6   6   20  0   0
10 BB   2019-11-26  6   6   6   54  12  0
11 BB   2019-11-27  5   6   6   0   0   1
12 BB   2019-11-28  4   5   5   0   0   2
13 BB   2019-11-29  5   6   6   90  33  0
```

I am trying to determine if the sum of C4 and C5 is 0, add 1 to the value above but if not then = 0

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a group using `cumsum` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(C4 + C5 != 0)) %>%
  mutate(new_col = cumsum(as.integer(C4+C5==0))) %>%
  select(-grp)

# A tibble: 13 x 8
#   ID    Date          C1    C2    C3    C4    C5 new_col
#   <chr> <chr>      <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>   <dbl>
# 1 AA    2019-11-25     6     6     6     0     0       1
# 2 AA    2019-11-26     6     6     6     0    18       0
# 3 AA    2019-11-27     5     6     6     0     0       1
# 4 AA    2019-11-28     4     5     5    65    60       0
# 5 AA    2019-11-29     5     6     6     0     0       1
# 6 AA    2019-11-30     5     6     6     0     0       2
# 7 AA    2019-12-01     5     6     6     0     0       3
# 8 AA    2019-12-02     4     5     5    65    60       0
# 9 BB    2019-11-25     6     6     6    20     0       0
#10 BB    2019-11-26     6     6     6    54    12       0
#11 BB    2019-11-27     5     6     6     0     0       1
#12 BB    2019-11-28     4     5     5     0     0       2
#13 BB    2019-11-29     5     6     6    90    33       0
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", 
"AA", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB"), Date = c("2019-11-25", "2019-11-26", 
"2019-11-27", "2019-11-28", "2019-11-29", "2019-11-30", "2019-12-01", 
"2019-12-02", "2019-11-25", "2019-11-26", "2019-11-27", "2019-11-28", 
"2019-11-29"), C1 = c(6L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 
5L, 4L, 5L), C2 = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
5L, 6L), C3 = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 
6L), C4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 65L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 65L, 20L, 54L, 0L, 0L, 
90L), C5 = c(0L, 18L, 0L, 60L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 60L, 0L, 12L, 0L, 
0L, 33L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```